# Complicated order By - Suborder by Query

Tags: mysql, sql

I need to perform a summary calculation for the below mentioned table structure for i need to order by "sessionId" and subgroup by the "sequenceId". Particular session can have one or more sequence. each sequence starts with one and move ahead sequencailly. primary keys and flow-squence may not be in tandem.

table >>

```
pk_id  session-id    sequence   some_other columns
  1    AAAAAAAA          1        blah-blah-blah
  2    AAAAAAAA          2        blah-blah-blah 
  3    AAAAAAAA          3        blah-blah-blah
  4    AAAAAAAA          2        blah-blah-blah
  5    AAAAAAAA          1        blah-blah-blah
  6    AAAAAAAA          3        blah-blah-blah
  7    AAAAAAAA          3        blah-blah-blah
  8    AAAAAAAA          2        blah-blah-blah
  9    AAAAAAAA          1        blah-blah-blah
```

I need to order by

```
 pk_id  session-id    sequence   some_other columns
  1    AAAAAAAA          1        blah-blah-blah
  2    AAAAAAAA          2        blah-blah-blah 
  3    AAAAAAAA          3        blah-blah-blah

  5    AAAAAAAA          1        blah-blah-blah
  4    AAAAAAAA          2        blah-blah-blah
  6    AAAAAAAA          3        blah-blah-blah

  9    AAAAAAAA          1        blah-blah-blah
  8    AAAAAAAA          2        blah-blah-blah
  7    AAAAAAAA          3        blah-blah-blah
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: it is important to know the exact columns as it affects the groupby.

Comment: This looks more like an `ORDER BY` question; in what way do you want to "group" anything?

Comment: Thanks bob duell.  i apologize its an order by question basic  we do processing of records group by session-id. i should have said order by..

Comment: What factors determine each grouping of 3?  for example how do you know PK_ID 1,2,3 are in the same group and it's not pk_Id 5,2,3 and 1,4,6

Comment: so what lets you know that a group of session-ids is in a new sequence -- the pk-id is lower?

Comment: #1 session-id is the primary group. with in that there are multiple flow sequence which starts from 1 to N.

Comment: Factors determining PK_ID ,1,2,3 is the flow sequence. anythiny flow sequence starts with 1 forms another sub-group

Comment: is flow sequence a field that is contianed in some_other column?  or maybe I missunderstood something I still have no idea how pK_ID 1,2,3 and 5,4,6 and 9.8,7 are grouped other than how you displayed them.  Without this attribute I don't know how anyone could figure this out.  Is it that PKID's 1-3 and 4-6 and 7-9 denote groups such that 10-12, 13-15, 16-18, 19-21 would also be defined groups and that you just want sequence sorted first by lowest PK in that group but overridden by the sequence such that 9,8,7 is listed in that order and 3rd in your set?

Comment: #xQbert - thanks. well for a particular session we record user activities in a sequential mode. user can cancel and restart flow in a same session that time their flow-sequence starts again.  by the way when ever flow-sequence is one then its separate block. problem in inserting sequential relays on the network call reachability. application sends it sequential but network (http) delay makes it jumbled via pk_id. so currently we are using order by session_id, id, flow_sequence. but likely above mentioned condition may not return things in right order

Answer (score 3):

Assuming you want to group together the first `sequence=1` with the first `sequence=2` and the first `sequence=3`, and similarly the second `1` with the second `2` and second `3` and so on (using `pk_id` as the order), you could use variable assignment to number `sequence` values, then use the resulting numbers for sorting.

This is what I mean:

```
SELECT
  pk_id,
  session_id,
  sequence,
  some_other_column
FROM (
  SELECT
    @row := (session_id = @sid AND sequence = @seq) * @row + 1 AS row,
    pk_id,
    @sid := session_id AS session_id,
    @seq := sequence AS sequence,
    some_other_column
  FROM
    atable,
    (SELECT @row := 0, @sid := '', @seq := 0) AS s
  ORDER BY
    session_id,
    sequence,
    pk_id
) AS s
ORDER BY
  session_id,
  row,
  sequence
;
```

This query can be tested [at SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/14766/10).

Comment: How easier would this be with a timestamp field.

Comment: @Hogan: Much more natural, yes.